# Self hosting ASMX in WCF application - How do you get the exact same SOAP produced?

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl, asmx

This is not a question about addressing.

I have an ASMX service, defined the usual way with `WebService()`, `WebServiceBinding()` and `WebMethod()` attributes.

Now, I'd like to use WCF to deliver this functionality, via  self-hosted solution.
I've tried using `ServiceContract()` and `OperationContract()` attributes with equivalent Namespace parameters to what is in the ASMX service and even though the WSDL generated looks similar, when a client designed to work with the ASMX service posts to the WCF version, I don't see the methods being invoked.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you show your code?  Also, are you using `basicHttpBinding`?  You'll need to use that to get SOAP 1.1 (or define a custom binding) in order to interact with legacy ASMX.

Comment: Show what you have done please.

Comment: Did you get this solved? If so, share?